# Why does PHP creates wrong files?

Tags: php, file, fopen

I'm creating using PHP a file:

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__ . "/../folder/example_$array[nothing].txt", "w");
```

Problem is, that there are two files generated:

1. `example_.txt`
2. `example_test.txt`

I don't know, why there are created these two files. I just wanna have the `example_test.txt`, the other one is the undesirabled. I checked the directory using `var_dump` and the two files appear after the code above was executed. The function is also only one time called.

Does anyone know what can be the issue?

EDIT:
`$array` is read by a file and contains something like `["nothing" => "test", "something more" => "okay"]`.

Comment: What is the use of the variable $array? Should it not be: `"/../folder/example_$array[nothing].txt"` or why not just do `"/../folder/example_.txt"`

Comment: @d3r1ck Yeah, sorry, just edited it. And I'm justing needing the file `example_test.txt`, the `example_.txt` is the one I don't wanna have.

Comment: @1072, show us more code like u_mulder asked. We need to see the content of the $array variable.

Comment: @d3rick Just edited.

Comment: Need more. Add code leading up to it, not an explanation of the code. Lets see the actual code

Comment: `$number = "01";
 $file_information = fopen(__DIR__ . "/../folder/details_$number.json", "r");
 $array = json_decode(fgets($file_information), true);`

Comment: That's not helpful. You need more code. What you have provided does not equal what you are getting. Do you have a redirect or loop? Is the code contained in a function or method or a single by-itself-page?

Comment: 1 `fopen()` call will not create 2 files.

Comment: It's in a function, but it is only called once.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I know, because of that it is so strange.

Comment: Well if the lines are manageable (as in it's not 1000 lines) just post the function script

Comment: What should I post? In conclusion that is the script I posted. The commentary defines `$array` and the code inside the main question contains the rest. The function isn't doing anymore.

Comment: You should post what from: `function whatever($whatever) { code here }` the show the context of that function as you use it on the page `if($someting) whatever($array); else die('didn't work');` These are examples but this will help if these two formats are posted.

Comment: If you don't have a loop, you must be running the script twice. As @AbraCadaver said, it's impossible for one call to `fopen()` to create 2 files.

Comment: Add an `echo "Creating file example_$array[nothing].txt";` line to the function and see if this is echoed twice.

Comment: Function is only one time called, I checked it an also the variable. And I can't post the whole code, I tried it in small, but there it worked correctly. The error occurs anywhere in the multiple files, so I can't post all.

Comment: Is it possible, that `$array` is wrong formatted by `json_decode` so that it can't be included into filename?